# is CouchDB a good fit?

Tags: database, couchdb

I'm working on a to do list with a simple collaboration feature.
Basically a user says that he wants to share a group of todo items.

The structure is that a item belongs to a group and that group is available to a set of users.
Now to get the list of todo items for a specific user, I need to figure out all items in groups the user has access too.

So basically the structure looks somewhat like this:

user - group - item

What i want is given a user id I want the items for all the groups the user has access to.

From my early experiments it seems to be somewhat problematic to produce a view with the desired output.
Is CouchDB a good fit, or should I be looking for another database to work with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand it correctly, each group has a list of users and a list of items. Then, for each group, you can emit a row for each (user, item) pair:

```
emit(userId, { _id: itemId });
```

Querying the view with `key="userId"`, should give the correct result.

For example, if a group document has the following structure:

```
{
  "_id": "Group_gid1",
  "userIds": ["User_uid1", ..., "User_uidN"],
  "itemIds": ["Item_iid1", ..., "Item_iidM"]
}
```

Your map function can be something like (not tested!!!):

```
function (doc) {
  var i, ii, userId, j, jj, itemId, ids = doc._id.split('_');
  if (ids[0] === 'Group' && doc.userIds && doc.itemIds) {
    for(i = 0, ii = doc.userIds.length, jj = doc.itemIds.length; i < ii; i += 1) {
      userId = doc.userIds[i];
      for(j = 0; j < jj; j += 1) {
        itemId = doc.itemIds[j];
        emit(userId, { _id: itemId });
      }
    }
  }
}
```

If you query it with `key="User_1"&include_docs=true` it should return all items in the groups of the user with `_id=="User_1"`.

Comment: This requires that the model has the userid in the item model, doesn't it? I cannot link through.

Comment: No... I've added a sample code in the answer. Hope it helps to make it more clear. I've changed the emitted value to `{_id: itemId}`, so you can get the item docs (instead of only the ids) when querying with `include_docs=true`.

Comment: Yeah, that would work. looking up on the middle entity and work with a lists of both types on that...